# Why can't i see characters above string initial length?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm implementing text rendering system for my engine right now. This time i come with a very strange problem: I have one text geometry that contains generated buffers and i regenerate them every time text changes. To set buffers i use `glBufferData` and to update it - `glBufferSubData`. This works perfectly until i want to make my buffers bigger (to contain at least one more char). To do so, i'm using `glBufferData` again. I see that new buffers are coming to their target GPU buffer, but i don't see new characters. Thats the exact problem. For example I can set new text as `new String(new char[2])`. That means i can type only 2 characters.
I can see and manipulate all characters under initial limit, but not above. If i change `glBufferSubData` to `glBufferData` nothing happens. Also I tried to destroy buffers, tried to create new pointers... nothing changed.

Here comes my GLTracer log:

```
[22.03.2015 13:39:38] [--------GAME_STARTED--------]
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetBoolean(GL_COLOR_ARRAY) -> false
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetBoolean(GL_TEXTURE_2D) -> false
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetBoolean(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY) -> false
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetBoolean(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY) -> false
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetBoolean(GL_INDEX_ARRAY) -> false
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetBoolean(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY) -> false
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetBoolean(GL_NORMALIZE) -> false
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetInteger(GL_MATRIX_MODE) -> GL_MODELVIEW
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetBoolean(GL_DEPTH_TEST) -> false
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetBoolean(GL_ALPHA_TEST) -> false
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetBoolean(GL_STENCIL_TEST) -> false
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetInteger(GL_DEPTH_FUNC) -> GL_LESS
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetInteger(GL_CULL_FACE_MODE) -> GL_BACK
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetBoolean(GL_BLEND) -> false
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetInteger(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING) -> 0
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetInteger(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_BINDING) -> 0
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetInteger(GL_TEXTURE_BINDING_2D) -> 0
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glEnableClientState(GL_INDEX_ARRAY) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glCullFace(Off) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glDepthFunc(LessOrEqual) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, -1) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(ElementArray, -1) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindTexture(Texture2D, -1) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGetInteger(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, java.nio.DirectIntBufferU[pos=0 lim=16 cap=16]) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGenTextures() -> 1
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindTexture(Texture2D, 1) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glTexParameteri(Texture2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glTexParameteri(Texture2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] [Setting wrap mode: Clamp]
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glTexParameteri(Texture2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glTexParameteri(Texture2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace]  -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] [Setting filter mode: Linear]
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glTexParameteri(Texture2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glTexParameteri(Texture2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace]  -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] [Setting texture environment mode: Modulate]
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glTexEnvi(Modulate)
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace]  -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glTexImage2D(Texture2D, 0, RGBA, 1024, 1024, 0, RGBA, UnsignedByte, java.nio.DirectByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=4194304 cap=4194304]) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGenBuffers() -> 1
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGenBuffers() -> 2
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGenBuffers() -> 3
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGenBuffers() -> 4
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 1) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBufferData(VertexArray, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=24 cap=24], Dynamic) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(ElementArray, 2) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBufferData(ElementArray, java.nio.DirectIntBufferU[pos=0 lim=8 cap=8], Dynamic) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 3) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBufferData(VertexArray, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=16 cap=16], Dynamic) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 4) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBufferData(VertexArray, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=12 cap=12], Dynamic) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glGenBuffers() -> 5
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 5) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBufferData(VertexArray, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=32 cap=32], Static) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glClear(ColorAndDepth) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glLoadIdentity() -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glMatrixMode(Projection) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glLoadIdentity() -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] gluPerspective(60.0, 1.3333334, 0.001, 5000.0) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glMatrixMode(ModelView) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, -1) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(ElementArray, -1) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindTexture(Texture2D, -1) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glLoadIdentity() -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glMatrixMode(Projection) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glLoadIdentity() -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] gluOrtho2D(0.0, 800.0, 600.0, 0.0) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glMatrixMode(ModelView) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glPushMatrix() -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glScalef(1.0, 1.0, 1.0) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glTranslatef(0.0, 500.0, 1.0) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glMultMatrix(java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=16 cap=16]) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glEnable(GL_BLEND) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBlendFunc(Alpha) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindTexture(Texture2D, 1) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 5) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glColorPointer(4, Float, 0, 0) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 1) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glVertexPointer(3, Float, 0, 0) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 4) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glNormalPointer(Float, 0, 0) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 3) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glTexCoordPointer(2, Float, 0, 0) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(ElementArray, 2) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glDrawElements(Quads, 8, UnsignedInt, 0) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glPopMatrix() -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 1) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBufferSubData(VertexArray, 0, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=12 cap=12]) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBufferSubData(ElementArray, 0, java.nio.DirectIntBufferU[pos=0 lim=4 cap=4]) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 3) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBufferSubData(VertexArray, 0, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=8 cap=8]) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 4) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBufferSubData(VertexArray, 0, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=12 cap=12]) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 1) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBufferSubData(VertexArray, 0, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=24 cap=24]) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBufferSubData(ElementArray, 0, java.nio.DirectIntBufferU[pos=0 lim=8 cap=8]) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 3) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBufferSubData(VertexArray, 0, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=16 cap=16]) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 4) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBufferSubData(VertexArray, 0, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=12 cap=12]) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 1) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBufferData(VertexArray, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=36 cap=36], Dynamic) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBufferData(ElementArray, java.nio.DirectIntBufferU[pos=0 lim=12 cap=12], Dynamic) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 3) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBufferData(VertexArray, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=24 cap=24], Dynamic) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBindBuffer(VertexArray, 4) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [GLTrace] glBufferData(VertexArray, java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU[pos=0 lim=12 cap=12], Dynamic) -> DONE
[22.03.2015 13:39:43] [---------GAME_ENDED---------]
```

Thanks in advance!

P.S. Tracer saves only first frame rendering calls. Then it shows next frames init calls. `glDraw` method works as should: vertex num changes. Using LWJGL 2.9.3.

BitmapText

```
public class BitmapText extends Text
{

    protected int limit;

    public BitmapText(float x, float y, String val, Font font)
    {
        super(val, font);
        limit = val.toCharArray().length;
        setController(ElementController.NULL);
        geometry = new Geometry();
        geometry.setLocation(x, y, 1f); // z?
        geometry.setMesh(new Mesh()
        {
            {
                renderMode = RenderingMode.Quads;
            }

            @Override
            public void init()
            {
                initialized = true;
            }

            @Override
            public void cleanup()
            {
                initialized = false;
            }
        });
        updateMaterial();
        setupMesh();
        updateMesh();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFont(Font font)
    {
        this.font = font;
        updateMaterial();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(String val)
    {
        this.value = val;
        int tlimit = val.toCharArray().length;
        if (limit < tlimit) {
            limit = tlimit;
            geometry.getMesh().cleanup();
        }
        updateMesh();
    }

    public int getLimit()
    {
        return limit;
    }

    public void updateMaterial()
    {
        if (geometry.getMaterial() == null) {
            geometry.setMaterial(new Material());
            geometry.getMaterial().setTransparent(true);
            geometry.getMaterial().setBlendingMode(BlendingMode.Alpha);
        }
        geometry.getMaterial().setDiffuseMap(((BitmapFont) font).getTextureAtlas());
    }

    public void setupMesh()
    {
        VertexBuffer pb = (VertexBuffer) BufferManager.create(BufferType.Position, BufferUsage.Dynamic);
        VertexBuffer ib = (VertexBuffer) BufferManager.create(BufferType.Index, BufferUsage.Dynamic);
        VertexBuffer tb = (VertexBuffer) BufferManager.create(BufferType.TexCoord, BufferUsage.Dynamic);
        VertexBuffer nb = (VertexBuffer) BufferManager.create(BufferType.Normal, BufferUsage.Dynamic);
        Mesh m = geometry.getMesh();
        m.getBuffers().put(pb.getType().ordinal(), pb);
        m.getBuffers().put(ib.getType().ordinal(), ib);
        m.getBuffers().put(tb.getType().ordinal(), tb);
        m.getBuffers().put(nb.getType().ordinal(), nb);
    }

    public void updateMesh()
    {
        Mesh m = geometry.getMesh();
        VertexBuffer pb = m.getBuffer(BufferType.Position);
        VertexBuffer ib = m.getBuffer(BufferType.Index);
        VertexBuffer tb = m.getBuffer(BufferType.TexCoord);
        VertexBuffer nb = m.getBuffer(BufferType.Normal);

        TextureAtlas atlas = (TextureAtlas) geometry.getMaterial().getDiffuseMap();
        int[] idata = new int[value.length() * 4];
        float[] pdata = new float[idata.length * m.getVertexSize()];
        float[] tdata = new float[idata.length * m.getTexCoordSize()];
        float[] ndata = Quad.baseNormal; // will not work! @todo rework normal generation
        float cw = 64f;
        float ch = 64f;
        float k = 0.5f;
        float ow = 24f;
        for (int i = 0, iI = 0, pI = 0, tI = 0; i < value.length(); i++, iI += 4, pI += 12, tI += 8) {
            int c = (int) value.charAt(i);
            float tS = atlas.getCellSizeCoord();
            float tSX = atlas.getCellXCoord(c);
            float tSY = atlas.getCellYCoord(c);
            float tEX = tSX + tS * k;
            float tEY = tSY + tS;
            float sX = i * ow;
            float sY = 0;
            float eX = i * ow + cw * k;
            float eY = ch;

            idata[iI] = iI;
            idata[iI + 1] = iI + 1;
            idata[iI + 2] = iI + 2;
            idata[iI + 3] = iI + 3;

            pdata[pI] = sX;
            pdata[pI + 1] = sY;
            pdata[pI + 2] = 0;
            pdata[pI + 3] = eX;
            pdata[pI + 4] = sY;
            pdata[pI + 5] = 0;
            pdata[pI + 6] = eX;
            pdata[pI + 7] = eY;
            pdata[pI + 8] = 0;
            pdata[pI + 9] = sX;
            pdata[pI + 10] = eY;
            pdata[pI + 11] = 0;

            tdata[tI] = tSX;
            tdata[tI + 1] = tSY;
            tdata[tI + 2] = tEX;
            tdata[tI + 3] = tSY;
            tdata[tI + 4] = tEX;
            tdata[tI + 5] = tEY;
            tdata[tI + 6] = tSX;
            tdata[tI + 7] = tEY;
        }

        if (m.isInitialized()) {
            BufferManager.update(pb, ClientBufferManager.createNIO(pdata));
            BufferManager.update(ib, ClientBufferManager.createNIO(idata));
            BufferManager.update(tb, ClientBufferManager.createNIO(tdata));
            BufferManager.update(nb, ClientBufferManager.createNIO(ndata));
        } else {
            BufferManager.setup(pb, pdata, m.getVertexSize());
            BufferManager.setup(ib, idata, m.getRenderMode().getSize());
            BufferManager.setup(tb, tdata, m.getTexCoordSize());
            BufferManager.setup(nb, ndata, m.getVertexSize());
            m.init();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code make help get the answer.

Comment: @Zielu. It will be pretty hard to post all chain. What you actually interested in? Posted BitmapText class.

Comment: it was general comment. It is not my expertise so I will not even try. But I doubt someone can fix your problem by looking at the log. If the code is too long post it somewhere and place link to it.

Comment: @Zielu. GLTracer logs every call to OpenGL and i'm pretty sure generation code and nio buffers are ok. So it comes a server-side problem. If so i don't think you actually need client code but you wan't to know what calls done to OpenGL.

Comment: OK, not my field if you sure it is enough it is enough.

Comment: @Zielu. Thanks. I'm not sure in anything - everything is relative!) If anyone needs code - i'll post what you want to know.

Comment: One thing that shows in the trace is that you're enabling `GL_COLOR_ARRAY`, and initially fill the corresponding buffer (5) with data. But then, when you update the buffers, you never update that one.

Comment: `GL_COLOR_ARRAY` isn't matter. I'm also trying to detect where in the code i'm setting up 5th buffer... Anyway that can't prevent to such problems. If you look to buffers i'm sending, you may notice that they are correct (except normal buffers with const lim=12) - the data changes when i change text value. Also, I know that `glDrawElements` count changes. So i really don't know why if i set limit to n i can't get over it...

Comment: As long as `GL_COLOR_ARRAY` is enabled, it does matter. You have the TexEnv mode set to `GL_MODULATE`, so the texture color will be multiplied by the vertex color. If you don't want to use the color array, you need to disable it, and set the current color.

Comment: As far as i know, we need `GL_COLOR_ARRAY` to be able to use color arrays. If we don't want to - we don't use them. That's an option and not the real source of my current problem.

Comment: Then what is the real source of your problem?

Comment: @RetoKoradi just forgot to answer that. That was the 5th buffer! When i update all buffers, i always forget to update color array which generated in material class at geometry creation. I just removed GL_COLOR_ARRAY.

Comment: Ok, I was pretty sure that was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just another example of bad programm structure. I didn't update color buffer that was created within a geometry.
If you sure all should be ok - turn off everything you can and try again.